# set dynamic path elfinder

Tags: php, elfinder

i'm using elfinder and i want to set path with php var (from my db connection)

here the array from my connector

```
include_once('../../include/header.php');
$CustomerUniqueCode=$InfoG->customer_unique_secure_code;

error_reporting(0); // Set E_ALL for debuging

require './autoload.php';
// ===============================================

function access($attr, $path, $data, $volume) {
return strpos(basename($path), '.') === 0       // if file/folder begins with '.' (dot)
    ? !($attr == 'read' || $attr == 'write')    // set read+write to false, other (locked+hidden) set to true
    :  null;                                    // else elFinder decide it itself
}
$opts = array(
//'debug' => true,
'roots' => array(
    array(
        'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',           // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
        'path'          => '../../folder/customer/'.$CustomerUniqueCode.'/files/',                 // path to files (REQUIRED)
        'URL'           => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '../../folder/customer/'.$CustomerUniqueCode.'/files/', // URL to files (REQUIRED)
        'tmbPath'       => '../files/thumbnails/',
        'tmbURL'        => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/../files/thumbnails',
        'uploadDeny'    => array('all'),                // All Mimetypes not allowed to upload
        'uploadAllow'   => array('image', 'text/plain'),// Mimetype `image` and `text/plain` allowed to upload
        'uploadOrder'   => array('deny', 'allow'),      // allowed Mimetype `image` and `text/plain` only
        'accessControl' => 'access'                     // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL)
        )
    )
);

// run elFinder
$connector = new elFinderConnector(new elFinder($opts));
$connector->run();
```

The error message is : 
Invalid backend configuration.
Readable volumes not available.

display_file.php including elfinder.php

Here the server organisation

[image]
Someone can help me ?

Comment: Which line returns that error?

Comment: what is the server organisation of your customer folder ?

Comment: path doesnt exist because $CustomerUniqueCode is empty...

Comment: customer folder is (exemple) :
folder/customer/ERze8n2KbS768Tbjk/files/

When i write this exact path everything is ok but when i replace unique code with my var it doesn't work...